# Override Navbar in Django base admin page to be same as the base.html

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my django admin pages, I would like to override the navbar (top ribbon) to be the same as the one in my "base.html" template. For different reasons:

- Users can navigate through the website even when they are in the admin views.
- To keep same style across pages, even in admin pages.

I am using django 2.2.6.

I don't really know how to start and what would be the best approach.

Any advices of how you would do this ?

---

**EDIT1:**

I was thinking about creating a base_site.html file within "templates/admin/" folder and just copy paste my base.html.

The problem I am facing is styling. Please see below for more details:

```
# Content of admin/base_site.html:
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<!--<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>--> # Uncommenting this line will "fix" style on my navbar but break style of all admin pages ...

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block usertools %}
<div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Group</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you may have understood, the navbar in my base.html is **using bootstrap** which for reason I ignored, when trying to importing boostrap in my **admin/base_site.html template is breaking style in general**.

Am I missing an important style for admin pages to be working? I was thinking admin page were already using bootstrap.

In that case, how style can be broken just by importing it in base_site.html?

If not, any idea how can I combine bootstrap with the missing css style ?

Answer (score 2):

All admin pages inherit from `admin/base_site.html`. In order override, you can override this template with your custom code.

Also this template should be loaded before admin app is loaded. Here are a couple of sample app templates that are overriding the base template.

[django-admin-env-notice](https://github.com/dizballanze/django-admin-env-notice/blob/master/django_admin_env_notice/templates/admin/base_site.html), 
 [django-admin-ribbon](https://github.com/skioo/django-admin-ribbon/blob/master/adminribbon/templates/admin/base_site.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and examples. Unfortunately, the problem I am facing is styling in django admin. (I have edited my post for more details). This is a weird one. Any luck you could help on this ?