# Django: Extending base.html in django admin

Tags: python, django

I've a base.html file which has vertical and horizontal menu-bar:

Wherever I want to use that I just simply write:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
//html code

{% endblock content %}
```

But I don't know how to use the same file `base.html` from templates directory in djando admin.

I want output like this:

[image]

What I Tried:

[How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates)

[How do I correctly extend the django admin/base.html template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978260/how-do-i-correctly-extend-the-django-admin-base-html-template)

[Override Navbar in Django base admin page to be same as the base.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279141/override-navbar-in-django-base-admin-page-to-be-same-as-the-base-html)

I tried few other solution just don't want to increase the length of question and `base.html` file's code just has basic bootstrap, html code for menus.

I am new to Django, little explanation would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is similar to `nav-global`.

Try this:

First create a folder in your `templates` folder as `admin` and create a html file(`base_site.html`) in the same folder

Assuming you have separate html file for menu-bars(Let's say the file is `nav.html`).

Write the below code in `base_site.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block nav-global %}
{% include 'nav.html' %} #Your navigation html file
{% endblock %}
```

Unrelated to question: I found a [git repo](https://github.com/cdrx/django-admin-menu) which will give you idea how to customize the django-admin menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can just extend the admin's base template as

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
```

For example:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <div>
        <h1>Extra links</h1>
        <a href="/admin/extra/">My extra link</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, make sure that you have added the `admin` app to the **`INSTALLED_APPS`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps,
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    
    # other apps,
]
```

Comment: {{ block.super }} is the thing that I was looking for :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue about a year and a half ago and I found a nice template loader on djangosnippets.org that makes this easy. It allows you to extend a template in a specific app, giving you the ability to create your own admin/index.html that extends the admin/index.html template from the admin app. Like this:

```
{% extends "admin:admin/index.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {{block.super}}
    <div>
        <h1>Extra links</h1>
        <a href="/admin/extra/">My extra link</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```